# Laravel Modules , create model,migration and controller in single command(artisan)

Tags: laravel, module, laravel-modules

I'm working on a modules Laravel project, and I wonder if it is possible to create model, migration and controller in single command (artisan).

I'm already aware of this command:

```
php artisan make:model Todo -mcr
```

This only works in a default Laravel project not a modular one.

I also read all the commands in [modular artisan commands docs](https://nwidart.com/laravel-modules/v1/advanced-tools/artisan-commands), but there is no mention of this issue.

Comment: The documentation on [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers) has example routes

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate, as the syntax you were using in Laravel 6 is no longer valid in Laravel 8+. It _can_ be if you would like to keep using it, which the linked question/answer demonstrates this.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#resource-controllers) :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController;
 
Route::resource('articles', ArticleController::class);
```